# java.lang.Object.equals() what was the intention?

Tags: java

What do you think the primary motive for putting the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method in `java.lang.Object` is?  Most of the implementations that we override it with are domain-centric, i.e. in model classes. I'm yet to see an implementation of `equals` in a factory class or something equivalent.

My conclusion is that it was primarily put in to support the Java Collection API, so that it could deal with any `Object`.  Else, it could have been left to be defined by specific domain designs.

PS: I know this thread may be more discussion oriented, but did not where else to get insight into this. I have tried to search far and wide for the answer to this, but always land up in discussions or explanations as to the difference between `==` and `equals` or the best practices of writing equals.

Comment: The Collection API was not in Java 1.0.

Comment: Ask James Gosling

Comment: You are right, it is to support `hashMap` and similar classes (initially it was `Hashtable`). They had to make it an instance method in order to leverage runtime polymorphism.

Comment: To the contrary, this is a perfectly valid question. It's not a very good fit for SO, that's all. So, closeable as not constructive--yes; downvotable--no.

Comment: @Bohemian In fact I was searching for a website that would allow me to do just that.

Comment: @nnhthuan You should browse more the new questions queue. This question at least makes sense and isn't especially lazy.

Comment: I do not think that this question is not constructive. It can be an interesting discussion. Indeed we have `Comparable` and even `Comparator` that is separate from the class. However `equals()` is implmented into class itself.

Comment: @AlexR Any question which invites discussion is "not constructive" in SO terms.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, could be an interesting discussion. But we do not want discussion on a Q&A site.

Comment: Wow! First question I've seen here that everybody agrees isn't fit for SO but wants to discuss. :)

Comment: If you want to discuss a question, you can 1) move it to [programmers]. 2) move it to the chat. 3) discuss in the comments. Please don't overdo that.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's `[programmers.se]` -> [programmers.se], by the way :P

Comment: Why not?  Does having `equals` in Object bother you or somehow upset your sensibilities?

Comment: @nnhthuan - I've seen several worse questions here today.  Not to say that this one is all that good.

Comment: The reason is *obviously* so that every object and every class has an `equals()` method. The point is barely worth mentioning let alone discussing. Not constructive.

Comment: @JanDvorak and others who have enlightened me by pointing me to the Programmers forum and explained why it is not a fit question for SO, thanks.  Didn't know regarding this forum.  I have flagged the question to be migrated.  Do not have enough rep to do it myself.  Hopefully it will get done.  Others who have given me insight into why they think it is so and how they would have done it +1.  I guess there is no right answer, but only opinions that can be discussed.

Comment: If the `toString` method were only specified in some sort of `Stringable` interface, then you would lose the ability to obtain a `String` representation of an arbitrary object.  Likewise, if you disallow comparing equality between two arbitrary objects (or getting hash codes), you handicap the programmer's ability to deal with arbitrary objects.  While it may not seem useful to have such methods in factory classes, if you want to store them in a no-duplicates-allowed data structure, then you would have need of one, even if the original programmer didn't think you would.

Answer (score 5):

By putting `equals` in `Object`, it lets many other classes use the `equals` method without knowing specifically what type of object it will be dealing with. For example, `HashMap` and `Hashtable` use `equals` as part of their algorithms.

An alternative to putting it in `Object` would to have a separate interface that has the `equals` method (or possibly combine it with `Comparable`, the specifics are not important here though). But, I'm guessing the Java designers thought that having a default `equals` implementation would be useful in some situations (and this ensures that all objects have an `equals` method).

Comment: I've often felt that there could've been an `Equatable` interface, and then a `Hashable` interface that extended it - `Comparable` would likewise extend `Equatable`. But as you point out, with interfaces you lose the trivial default implementations based on reference equality. It would be a lot of noise for not too much benefit.

Comment: Well, I do not like `equals` method in Object. It should have been an interface method. And the "noise" here is the default implementation based on reference equality, because in nearly every case when you need equality then it is the wrong implementation. You need to implement it on your own. Well, in the very few cases where reference equality is desired you save 4 lines of code. The price you pay for it does not worth it: You've an `equals` method on many objects where equality does not make sense - just noise. In a technical view it's perfectly fine, but practically I dislike the clutter.

Answer (score 3):

It was a pretty good language design decision to include `equals` in Java.

- Decades of experience have shown that different classes of object have different *equality semantics*. You need a mechanism to express this, and prividing a polymorphic `equals` method is a decent approach.
- Object identity (`==` in Java-land) is a reasonable default for equality testing but is not sufficient in many cases: often you want two objects to be considered equal even if they are not the same object (consider two lists with identical elements, for example)
- If you don't define `equals` at the top of the object heirarchy (`Object`) so that it is implemented for every object, then it's hard / impossible to write generic code that deals with equality.
- If you don't provide `equals` as part of the core language, you can expect hundred of different and incompatible variations to spring up in the library ecosystem. Not pretty!

My main criticism of the design of `equals` is that it assumes that you have a valid non-null object to call it on. Often true, but sometimes you need to check for nulls as well. As a result, I often end up using a static `equalsWithNulls` method or something simular that takes null checks into account before calling the regular `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive the intention was to follow Smalltalk's design which predates Java and includes (IIRC) `#=` and `#hash`. Gosling also liked the VM idea but kept the nasty C++ syntax. Also it was probably chosen because Java at the time did not support generics or multiple inheritance (or traits or mixins).

Personally I think `.equals()` is dangerous on mutable objects. Even more so its not type safe (I have had many accidental bugs comparing Strings to other objects). I think [Haskell's type classes](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) are the right way to do `equal` but Java does have a powerful enough type system to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Reference types are distinguished from primitives by having both identity and equality.  Consider the following:

- int a = 5;
- Integer a = Integer.valueOf(5);

The former has only the value 5 and the natural ordering of integers.  The latter, on the other hand has that -plus- the identity of its reference (as well as the ability to be represented by the null reference).

It makes sense to have the ability to test for both qualities.

Consider now:

- System.out.println(new Integer(5) == new Integer(5));

These Integers are equal, but not identical.  The output is false (let's assume that it's ok to simply ignore that static factory 'valueOf()' method for Integer).